# windows updates - completely disabled, yet still see periodic "Getting Windows Ready"

Tags: windows, windows-update

about to deploy many unattended machines into production, we do not wish to have windows updates applied automatically under any circumstances. We have a separate management process for application of critical hotfixes.

Despite having disabled windows updates multiple ways, we still experience on occasion "Getting Windows Ready" or "Don't turn your machine off" messages following a shut down or reboot. The machines then require a hard reboot.

Updates are disabled via methods:

1. Registry Update - DisableOSUpgrade & NoAutoUpdate
2. Changing all Network modes to 'metered'

Event viewer (WindowsUpdateClient) shows that "Windows Update successfully found 107 updates" today. So Windows is clearly looking and still thinks it should be doing something with these updates.

What further steps can I take to stop the windows update process and prevent these shut down messages?

Comment: What does your Windows Update History indicate?

Comment: You don’t indicate what version of Windows you are running.  Question is currently too broad to answer

Comment: @Ramhound windows 10 LTSB

Comment: Why are you leaving a comment instead of editing your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this policy:

```
Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update\Configure Automatic Updates
```

It will stop automatic updates but will not hide update options for users.